# Attribute Error when importing dictionary from module to another

Tags: python, dictionary, python-module

So I have 4 different classes which I need to combine into one class at the end in a program called "Main" . However whenever I run the Main program, it keeps throwing up an attribute error when it comes to accessing the `emp_det` dictionary from the `Employee` class into the other classes so I can use the generated Employee ID stored in the dictionary. (There are two more classes called `Weekly_Paid` and `Timecard` but I've only mentioned 3 for the sake of the brevity and because the error seems to be universal).
(All 3 classes are in different files.)

The error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Saloni/Documents/Case Sudy 3/MAIN.py", line 28, in <module>
s.MaintainTimecard()
  File "C:/Users/Saloni/Documents/Case Sudy 3\Monthly_Paid.py", line 24, in MaintainTimecard
if emp_id in Employee.emp_det:
AttributeError: module 'Employee' has no attribute 'emp_det'
```

Employee Class:

```
# ATTRIBUTES: emp_nm, emp_ph, emp_add,emp_id, emp_dob
from random import *
class Employee:
    emp_det={} #dictioary to save the details of the employees
    #emp_id:[emp_nm,emp_ph,emp_add,emp_dob]

    def add_emp(self):
        lst=[] #to store all inputed details
        print("Enter Employee Details:")
        emp_nm=input("Name: ")
        emp_ph=input("Contact Number: ")
        emp_add=input("Address: ")
        emp_dob=input("Date of Birth:")
        lst.extend([emp_nm,emp_ph,emp_add,emp_dob])  #store the details
        emp_id="emp"+str(randrange(1000,10000))
        while emp_id in Employee.emp_det:  # avoid repetition
            emp_id="emp"+str(randrange(1000,10000))
        Employee.emp_det[emp_id]=lst  # make dictionary key and store in list
        print("Your Employee ID is",emp_id)

    def del_emp(self):
        t=0  # to count number of invalid inputs
        while t<=3:
            emp_id=input("Employee ID:")
            if emp_id in Employee.emp_det:
                del Employee.emp_det[emp_id]
                t=4 # to get the program out of the loop
            else:
                print("Invalid ID. Try Again.")
                t+=1

    def edit_emp(self):
        t=0  # counting invalid inputs
        while t<=3:
            emp_id=input("Employee ID:")
            if emp_id in Employee.emp_det:  # checking validity
                print("\n Edit: \n 1.Contact \n 2.Address \n")
                ch=int(input("Option:"))
                if ch==1:
                    Employee.emp_det[emp_id][1]=input("New Contact Number:")
                elif ch==2:
                    Employee.emp_det[emp_id][2]=input("New Address:")
                else:
                    print("Invalid Option")
                t=4   #t o get the program out of the loop
            else:
                print("Invalid ID. Try Again.")
                t+=1

    def Edisplay(self):
        print("The Employees are:")
        print(" ID \t Name \t Contact \t Address \t Date of Birth")
        for i in Employee.emp_det:  # access to each dictionary element
            print(i,"\t",end=" ")
            for j in Employee.emp_det[i]:  # access every value under the key
                print(j,"\t",end=" ")
            print("\n")
```

Monthly-Paid Class

```
import Employee
import Timecard

class Monthly_Paid:
    fixSalary = 40000
    def AcceptTimeCard (self):
        print ("Timecard details are:")
        for i in Timecard.emp_tcinfo:
            print(i, "\t", end ="")
            for j in Timecard.emp_tcinfo[i]:
              print(j,"\t",end=" ")

    def Gen_Paycheck (self):
        emp_id = input("please enter employee ID")
        if emp_id in Employee.emp_det:
            print ("Total Salary of " + emp_id + " is :" + fixSalary)

    def MaintainTimecard (self):
        emp_id = input("Please enter your employee ID")
        if emp_id in Employee.emp_det:
            print("\n 1.Edit Start Time Hour "
                  "\n 2.Edit Start Time Minute "
                  "\n 3. Edit End Time Hour "
                  "\n 4.Edit End Time Minute")
            ch = int(input("Input option"))
            if ch == 1:
                Timecard.emp_tcinfo[emp_id][1] = input(
                                                "Input new Start Time Hour")
            if ch ==2:
                Timecard.emp_tcinfo[emp_id][2] = input(
                                                "Input new Start Time Minute")
            if ch == 3:
                Timecard.emp_tcinfo[emp_id][3] = input(
                                                "Input new End Time Hour")
            if ch == 4:
                Timecard.emp_tcinfo[emp_id][4] = input(
                                                "Input new End Time Minute")
            else:
                print("Invalid input")
```

Main script

```
print ("Welcome to Employee Time Card System")

import Employee

e= Employee.Employee()
e.add_emp()

print("What kind of employee are you?")
print ("\n 1.Monthly Paid \n 2.Weekly Paid")

ch= int(input("Enter Choice"))

if ch ==1:
    import Monthly_Paid
    import Timecard
    s = Monthly_Paid.Monthly_Paid()
    w = Timecard.Timecard()
    print("Monthly Paid")
    t1= "y"
    while t1=="y" or t1=="Y":
        print ("\n 1.See Time Card \n2.Edit TimeCard \n 3.See Paycheck")
        ch1 = int(input("Enter Choice"))
        if ch1 == 1:
            s.AcceptTimeCard
        if ch1 == 2:
            s.MaintainTimecard()
        if ch1 == 3:
            s.Gen_Paycheck()
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice")
            t1 = input("Continue with Monthly Paid? Y/N")
elif ch == 2:
    import Weekly_Paid
    a= Weekly_Paid.Weekly_Paid()
    t2= "y"
    print ("Weekly Paid")
    while t2=="y" or t2=="Y":
        print ("\n 1.See Time Card \n2.Edit TimeCard \n 3.See Paycheck")
        ch1 = int(input("Enter Choice"))
        if ch1 == 1:
            a.AcceptTimeCard()
        if ch1 == 2:
            a.MaintainTimeCard()
        if ch1 == 3:
            a.Gen_Paycheck()
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice")
        t2 = input("Continue with Weekly Paid? Y/N")
else:
    print("Invalid choice")
```

Comment: Are these code blocks the same file? If not could you split the code sample into the same structure as the files, please add the file names as well, it's important here.

Comment: They are different Files. Sorry, I edited the files  into 3 different blocks of code.

Comment: Please include the exact error traceback as well, that is important information in answering this question.

Comment: Done, and sorry again.

Comment: In future you will get much better help if you include all relevant error messages in your question. By including the error message I was immediately able to see what caused your issue. If my answer has been helpful feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import Employee` will look for a module Employee.py. If there is no file called `Employee.py` then you won't be able to make that import work.

So in the `Monthly-Paid Class` file you have to do something like:

`from path.to.employee_file_name import Employee`

The problem then arises from the fact that there's a module called `Employee` but that contains a class called `Employee`. Importing the module Employee doesn't give you access to the class automatically. To access the attribute of the 
`Employee` class called `emp_det` you have to specify the class. So if you imported using

`from Employee import Employee`

To access you need:

`Employee.emp_det`

Alternatively if you imported with:

`import Employee`

then to access you need:

`Employee.Employee.emp_det`